# Не могу разобраться с массивами php

Tags: php, массивы

Написал вот такой код

На выходе **var_dump($summ_all_prices_used);** получаю **float(30000) float(64634) float(264634)**

При сложении чисел в массиве он считает верно, конечный верный подсчёт в конце, вот **float(264634)**

Но почему выводятся первые 2 float, я не понимаю

И если числа в кол-во складываются больше, то и float больше становится

Мне нужна сумма всех чисел, то есть последний float

Как я могу только его получить?

```
$all_used = array();

            foreach ($bloggers_db as $bloggers)
            {
                //var_dump($bloggers->id);

                //var_dump($this->request->post('status_waiting_creatives')[4]);

                // Если отмечена галочка
                if ($this->request->post('status_waiting_creatives')[$bloggers->id] == 'on')
                {
                    //var_dump($this->request->post('status_waiting_creatives')[$bloggers->id]);

                    //var_dump($bloggers->id);

                    // Выводим сумму интеграции
                    $data_platforms__integration_cost_db = DataPlatformsForm::find()
                        ->where(['id_blogger' => $bloggers->id])
                        ->all();

                    ////foreach ($data_platforms__integration_cost_db as $data_platforms__integration_cost)
                    //{
                        //var_dump($data_platforms__integration_cost->integration_cost);
                        ////if ($this->request->post('status_waiting_creatives')[$bloggers->id] == 'on')
                        //{
                            $all_used[]=floatval($data_platforms__integration_cost_db[0]->integration_cost);
                            //$all_used[] = $data_platforms__integration_cost_db[0]->integration_cost;
                        //}
                        

                        //var_dump($all_used);



                        // Кладем цену в массив
                        //$all_used[]=floatval($data_platforms__integration_cost->integration_cost);

                        
                    //}

                    $summ_all_prices_used = 0;

                    foreach($all_used as $used)
                        {
                            $summ_all_prices_used += $used;

                            //var_dump($used);
                        }

                       //echo array_sum($summ_all_prices_used);

                    var_dump($summ_all_prices_used);

                    //echo $summ_all_prices_used;

                    
                    
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл косяк

Я этот код

```
$summ_all_prices_used = 0;

                    foreach($all_used as $used)
                        {
                            $summ_all_prices_used += $used;

                            //var_dump($used);
                        }

                       //echo array_sum($summ_all_prices_used);

                    var_dump($summ_all_prices_used);

                    //echo $summ_all_prices_used;
```

За foreach не вынес